# Camera getting automatically zoomed in to object?

Tags: rendering

When I try to render my object (I am using blender 2.91) it automatically renders closely to the object, but in the viewport, it is just where I want it (see images). This happens in both Cycles and Eevee render.
I can I fix this?

Blend file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/th3ciy0yj5g36se/Problem.blend/file
[image: Render]

[image: Viewport]

Comment: When I open the .blend file you’ve uploaded, I see [a camera pointed at absolutely nothing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W01Yj.png). Zooming out, [you can see the placement of the camera relative to other objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz5Bh.jpg). Do you see something different when you open the same .blend file?

Comment: Now it finally worked. it was pointed at it, but all i had to do is change it to material mode